# Definition of C++ template specialization member function

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following class and specializations.  How would I implement the function bodies for the template class and both specializations outside of the class definition?  Obviously, each function implementation would need to be declared `inline`.

```
template <typename T1, typename = void>
struct MyClass
{
    void func();
};
template <typename T1>
struct MyClass<T1, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T1>::value>>
{
    void func();
};
template <typename T1>
struct MyClass<T1, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T1>::value>>
{
    void func();
};
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be [c++14]? C++11 doesn't have `std::enable_if_t`; you'd have to write `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`

Comment: This is VS2015 Update 3, which is mostly C++11, but has a couple of C++14 library bits implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have an out-of-class definition of a member function of a template class, you repeat the template arguments so you can form the name of the class.

Basically, to define this `func()`:

> ```
> template <typename T1, typename = void>
> struct MyClass
> {
>     void func();
> };
> ```

You'd write:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void MyClass<T1, T2>::func() {}
```

To define this one:

> ```
> template <typename T1>
> struct MyClass<T1, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T1>::value>>
> {
>     void func();
> };
> ```

You'd write:

```
template <typename T1>
void MyClass<T1, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T1>::value>>::func() {}
```

[Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/U1nbM7)