# Definition of C++ template specialization not working when expected

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930163/definition-of-c-template-specialization-member-function).  The answer to that question works as advertised.  However, I was struggling to apply it to my actual code.  I now have an example that does not work, but I believe matches the previous question's answer.

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace Internal
{
    template <template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
    struct IsInstantiation : std::false_type {};

    template <template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
    struct IsInstantiation<TT, TT<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

    template <typename T1, typename = void>
    struct MyClass
    {
        void func(int i);
    };

    template <typename T1>
    struct MyClass<T1, std::enable_if_t<IsInstantiation<MyClass, T1>::value>>
    {
        void func(int i);
    };
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline void Internal::MyClass<T1, T2>::func(int i) {}

template <typename T1>
inline void Internal::MyClass<T1, std::enable_if_t<Internal::IsInstantiation<Internal::MyClass, T1>::value>>::func(int i) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Internal::MyClass<int> mc1;
    Internal::MyClass<Internal::MyClass<int>> mc2;

    mc1.func(0);
    mc2.func(0);
}
```

I am compiling this code with VS2015 Update 3.  On the second definition of `func` it gives the following errors :

> - `void Internal::MyClass<T1,<unnamed-symbol>>::func(int)`: function template has already been defined
> - `Internal::MyClass<T1,<unnamed-symbol>>`: too few template arguments

What am I missing that is causing this to fail to compile?

Comment: cannot reproduce with clang++ (6.0.0) ot g++ (7.2.0) (but compiled C++14, not C++11, because `std::enable_if_t`)

Comment: VS2015 is (mostly) a C++11 compiler with a handful of C++14 libraries.  Can you reproduce compiling it as C++11?

Comment: cannot reproduce also compiling C++11 (but, obviously, with `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<...>`)

Comment: I will get VS2017 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: You will need c++14 for that.

Comment: Appears to be a VC++ defect.  Same issue with latest version of VS2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a VC++ bug.  It should be fixed in a (near) future update to VC++2017.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/237932/function-definition-of-template-specialization-not.html